# github pull request failing because ci/circleci timed out

Tags: node.js, github, google-cloud-platform, git-pull, circleci

I forked the sample code for Google tutorials, fixed a bug using the github editor, and issued a pull request (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/pull/567).  This was my first time doing both.

It fails with this message: `The Some checks were not successful`
Details:  `ci/circleci — A command timed out during your tests`

When I click 'details', the circleci site (https://circleci.com/gh/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/1533?utm_campaign=vcs-integration-link&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=github-build-link) gives me this (see below).

Can anyone help me understand how to proceed?

**Title 1**

```
$ functions start && cd functions/datastore && npm run system-test && functions stop
config10:04 (timed out)
```

**Details 1**

```
$functions start && cd functions/datastore && npm run system-test && functions stop
Enter a projectId to get started: projectId:  
command functions start && cd functions/datastore && npm run system-test && functions stop took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

**Title 2**

```
$ functions start && cd functions/helloworld && npm run test && functions stop
10:03 (timed out)config
```

**Details 2**

```
$functions start && cd functions/helloworld && npm run test && functions stop
Enter a projectId to get started: projectId:  
command functions start && cd functions/helloworld && npm run test && functions stop took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that those tests sometimes take longer than 10 minutes, which is the default timeout time in CircleCI.

This config really should be converted to CircleCI 2.0, but that's a separate issue. For now, putting in longer timeouts might help: https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#modifiers

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Thank you very much.  It looks like it is waiting for a projectID ('Enter a projectId to get started: projectId: ').  I don't know that more time will address that.  Is there something else I should be doing to make circleci aware of a projectID?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dumb question: should the GitHub project be providing the project ID (`GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples`) or should this be Arie Fisher's Github project?